# Containers in Docker Swarm unable to communicate with each other

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have three different nodes with the following specs:

- Node A + B: Ubuntu 16.04 + Docker 18.03.0-ce based on [this image](https://github.com/scaleway-community/scaleway-docker).
- Node C: CoreOS stable + Docker 17.12.0-ce

All joined into a swarm with host A being the manager. Node C is hosted on a geographically different server location by a different provider but that *should* not matter since I only use public IP addresses for things like `--advertise-addr`.

I have made sure [all ports needed for swarm communications](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#open-protocols-and-ports-between-the-hosts) are open on all nodes. Especially port `7946` is said to be needed for inter-container communication. [Using netcat](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-netcat-to-establish-and-test-tcp-and-udp-connections-on-a-vps) I am able to send and receive TCP and UDP packets between all three nodes and also from a test container within each of the nodes to each other node.

Inspecting the network on *any* node shows me the same result: All three nodes are listed. So Docker Swarm seems to be aware of its peers on any node.

Now here is the problem:

- Containers hosted on nodes A + B can reach each other via the overlay network without any problems
- Containers hosted on A + C or B + C can *not* communicate. Connections just time out.

I can not find any obvious difference between the nodes other than the operating system and the docker version. Looking at the linked image of the Ubuntu servers, I saw that there are several tools such as `pipework` installed, but I didn't configure or use it. Or does Docker Swarm use it implicitly?

I am really stuck here. Sorry if this question feels incomplete, I simply don't know where to start analyzing the issue. Please feel free to comment, if I should amend further information to this question.

Comment: Did you tried `--listen-addr` option as well (along with  `--advertise-addr`) while registering slaves to the swarm? if not please do so, this will tell how swarm manager would find slave nodes (specially when you have more than one Ethernet interfaces)

Comment: Not sure about `--listen-addr`, I will test it as soon as possible. But since all slaves are correctly listed in the swarm and only the container-to-container communication fails, I don't think it is an issue of the manager not finding the slaves.

Comment: I have encountered the same few months back. Where I was able to see list of nodes by SWARM Managers but I faced issue to deploy services on docker-swarm . Give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I found the reason: The "unreachable" server (even though it was able to join the swarm) used the virtual network adapter driver `e1000`. After changing it to `virtio`, everything works as a charm.

I hope this might be of some help to anyone having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall settings. They tends to break docker "networks" suite often.

Make sure network interface docker0 can reach the network for in- and outbound traffic.

Comment: As I said, I've verified that communication on the documented ports works between all three servers. Didn't find any problems there. But I still need to check about the docker0 interface. Didn't explicitly listen on it yet.

Comment: You may miss outbound traffic authorization for docker0 interfaces.